# I'm trying to configure CRUD Group (FOS User Bundle)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, crud, fosuserbundle

I'm following **Using Groups With FOSUserBundle** Doc Symfony https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/groups.html.

And after i'm generating **CRUD Group Controller** Based on a Doctrine Entity

=> `$ php app/console generate:doctrine:crud`

So, I have :

**GroupRole.php**

```
<?php
// src/BISSAP/UserBundle/Entity/GroupRole.php

namespace BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group as BaseGroup;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_group")
 */
class GroupRole extends BaseGroup
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

**Part of vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bunde/ModelGroup.php**

```
abstract class Group implements GroupInterface

{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $roles;

public function __construct($name, $roles = array())
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->roles = $roles;
}
[...]
}
```

**Part of GroupController.php** *(CRUD Symfony generating)*

```
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new GroupRole();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

return $this->render('BISSAPUserBundle:GroupRole:new.html.twig', array(
    'entity' => $entity,
    'form'   => $form->createView(),
));
}
```

**Part of grouprole.yml**

```
grouprole_new:
    path:     /new
    defaults: { _controller: "BISSAPUserBundle:GroupRole:new" }
```

When i access to ***../web/app_dev.php/grouprole/new*** to create a new group by the Form from **GroupRoleController.php**, I get error :

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group::__construct(), called in /var/www/bodykoncept/src/BISSAP/UserBundle/Controller/GroupRoleController.php on line 81 and defined
```

Normally, when I created a new entity by CRUD Controller, I don't need to pass any arguments to __construct()!?

Maybe are there an another way to used CRUD with group FOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistakes in your constructor, which are whats causing your issue.

*current*

```
$entity = new GroupRole();
$form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
```

This is not the way you create a form in Symfony.  You must [create a formType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_form.html) class, and pass that to `$this->createForm(xx)` (notice you've typo'd the method call as well).

Once you create a formtype, which might looks something like this:

**AppBundle/Form/GroupRoleType.php**

```
class GroupRoleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class);
        // ... plus whatever other fields you want
    }
}
```

then in your controller:

**AppBundle/Controller/GroupController**

```
$groupRole = new GroupRole('something');
$form = $this->createForm(GroupRoleType::class, $groupRole); 

$form->handleRequest($request);
```

> Its worth nothing here that `createForm` takes a 2nd param, which defines the initial data in the form.  If you pass in your new groupRole object, itll prepopulate the form with the name field, which your user can then change. If you dont want to do this, pass in nothing, and create your new groupRole object after the submit and manually bind the data to it from the form.

Symfony will know that the original class has a construct, and use the form to populate it.

Comment: => I want to use NewAction from the controller to get a simple empty Form to create a new Group. with field : (id), Name and Roles. If i used `$entity = new GroupRole('someName');` how can I get a form with empty field?

Comment: this is why I suggested using a `groupRole` entity is an odd decision.  The `FOS::basegroup()` already has the ability to add roles to it.  I think youve confused things in your design phase.

Comment: odd?, but i just fallowed this => https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/groups.html;

Comment: Ok Id totally missed the error, Ive changed my answer which hopefully will help you.

Comment: On more thing, you said there are mistakes in Controller `$form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity)` but this Controller are generated by `php app/console generate:doctrine:crud` so is odd there are mistakes...

Comment: it is odd, but that is a mistake. you should report it